# Html.CheckBox not being set [asp.net mvc 4]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am having a bit of a headache with a thing (I know something like has been asked before, but I'm pretty sure it's not quite the same thing).
To the point:
I have a View with a Telerik grid. On that grid I show some stuff from the model that I pass to the View BUT I want in the final column to put a CheckBox that is checked/unchecked based on some things in the Controller (the checks have nothing to do with the model that is being passed). In my ActionResult function that takes care of the View I store some `Boolean` values in the ViewData, and then I set the isChecked value in the CheckBox based on the values stored in the ViewData.

The code for the ActionResult is as follows:

```
    [SecureThis(Roles = "User")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //get bucket ids
        var buckets = db.Buckets.ToList();
        int i=1;
        string cb = "checkbox" + i.ToString();
        foreach (Bucket b in buckets)
        {
            var payByInvoice = db.PaymentOptions.Where(p => p.BucketId == b.Id).Select(p => p.CanPayByInvoice).SingleOrDefault();
            if (payByInvoice == (int)PayByInvoiceState.Accepted)
                ViewData["checkbox" + i.ToString()] = true;
            else ViewData["checkbox" + i.ToString()] = false;
                i++;
                cb = "checkbox" + i.ToString();
        }
        return View(db.Buckets);
    }
```

And the grid that should show all the stuff is this:

```
@{
int i=1;
string cb = "checkbox" + i.ToString();
 }
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("BucketsGrid")
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(bucket => bucket.Id))
        .Columns(
            columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(model => ViewData[model.Id.ToString()])
                    .HeaderTemplate(
                    @<b>@Strings.Title_Customer</b>
                    );
                columns.Bound(model => model.CreditFacility);
                columns.Bound(model => model.Minimum);
                columns.Bound(model => model.RefillLevel);
                columns.Bound(model => model.NotificationEmail);
                columns.Bound(model => model.NotificationSms);
                columns.Template(model => Html.ActionLink(Strings.Edit, "Edit", new { id = model.Id }));
                columns.Template(model => Html.ActionLink(Strings.NotificationOptions, "Bucket", "NotificationOptions", new { id = model.Id }, null));
                columns.Template(model => Html.ActionLink("Refill", "Refill", "Payment", new { id = model.Id }, null));
                columns.Template(model => Html.ActionLink(Strings.Details, "Details", new { id = model.Id }));
                columns.Template(model => Html.ActionLink(Strings.Delete, "Delete", new { id = model.Id }));
                columns.Template(model => Html.CheckBox("invoice", (Boolean)ViewData[@cb])).HeaderTemplate("Invoice Option");                                
                @i++;
                @cb = "checkbox" + i.ToString();
            }
        )
        .Pageable(paging =>
                paging.Enabled(true)
                      .PageSize(UserSettings.GridPageSize)
                      .Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPrevious)
                      .Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom)
            )
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Resizable(resize=> resize.Columns(true))
)
```

The problem with this whole thing is that the checkboxes remain unchecked, no matter the data stored in the ViewData. I went with the debugger and the values are se accordingly in the ViewData, but for some reason (that I cannot yet tell) the checkboxes still remain unchcked.

Any ideas on this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know if the problem is specific to the telerik? Can you put a plain Html.Checkbox somewhere on the page and see what you get?

Comment: @Rowan I don't think it's because of the Telerik grid. The CheckBox is from the HtmlHelper (not from the Telerik), and if I explicitly put true instead of the `(Boolean)ViewData[@cb]` the CheckBoxes appear checked.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the CheckBox to something from ViewData? `Html.Checkbox(ViewData[@cb].ToString(), True)`

Comment: Hm...I never thought of doing that. I'll give you my feedback on monday because I just left from work and I don't have the project at home. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's happening but I'm like you in that I want to poke and prod it to find out ;)

Comment: @RowanFreeman Hello, so I'm back at work and I tried what you suggested. It returns the right true/false values, I even iterated with the debugger to see the values, they are all corret. Also tried converting with `Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData[@cb].ToString())` and it is still not working.

Comment: It's something to do with the telerik, and I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: I see, so you think it's because the Telerik controls... Well thanks for the help. If I find the solution I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the problem of all this. As expected, it was my own doing (or so to say). The problem was that I incremented the @i variable inside the Telerik grid declaration, thinking that it would happen for all the rows in the grid, but that thing is only triggered once. Hence, the `ViewData[@cb]` value would always have the 2nd value set in the Controller (which in my case was `false`) and all the checkboxes would then be unchecked.

The fix:

I used the ViewBag and set it up with a `Dictionary<Guid, bool>` to hold my values, and iterate through it using the `model.Id` property. For anyone who might be interested I'll post the code below.

Controller:

```
        ViewBag.Dict = new Dictionary<Guid, bool>();
        Dictionary<Guid, bool> dict = new Dictionary<Guid, bool>();

        foreach (Bucket b in buckets)
        {
            var payByInvoice = db.PaymentOptions.Where(p => p.BucketId == b.Id).Select(p => p.CanPayByInvoice).SingleOrDefault();
            if (payByInvoice != (int)PayByInvoiceState.Accepted)
            {
                dict.Add(b.Id, false);
            }
            if (payByInvoice == (int)PayByInvoiceState.Accepted)
            { 
                dict.Add(b.Id, true);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Dict = dict;
```

View:

```
columns.Template(model => Html.CheckBox("invoice", (bool)ViewBag.Dict[model.Id])).HeaderTemplate("Invoice option");
```